# how to apply and showing Change the header height of the crystal report in the viewer using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i use this code to increase the height header  of crystal report

`CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = print_report1 ' 
msgbox(print_report1.Section2.Height)  '// print value 4000
print_report1.Section2.Height = 10000
msgbox(print_report1.Section2.Height)  '// print value 10000
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()`

the height change from 4000 to 10000 when print the new height  value , but not appear the new height in the viewer ?

EDIT ' 
The change appears only when the update icon is clicked in the viewer and does not appear by the code
`CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed it after long search , i just use this code  to update shape of report

```
 CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```